# Build and Integration Environment for Java/Java EE

Tags: java, build-process, build, continuous-integration, build-automation

is there such a thing in a standard manner?

including

Java Source Code - Test Code -
Ant or Maven
JUnit
Continuous Integration (possibly Cruise Control)
ClearCase Versioning Tool
Deploy to Application Server

in the end I 'd like to have an automatic Build and Integration Environment.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

Comment: Hudson integrates very nicely with maven.  Maven integrates well with JUnit.  Maven is also pretty agnostic about your exact version control system.  You'll also want to consider a managed Maven repository like Artifactory or Nexus, and adding Sonar into the mix for build metrics isn't a bad idea either.

For integration tests you'll want to look at something like selenium, but setting up Hudson for more than unit testing is a subject for another question...

Answer (score 1):

There are no end of possible solutions. Take a look at the [continuous integration matrix](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix), which details common solutions, and their associated features. Hopefully you should be able to make a decision based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Continuum](http://continuum.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A tool set could be

[IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html)

Ant

- The ant files can be generated by intellij
- Then you need to write some ant to run your tests!
- Then you need to write some ant to package your application
- Then you need to write some ant to deploy your application

  - including configuring queues, databases etc ([dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/) might work for this)

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

Subversion - Its nice and easy. ClearCase is shocking don't go near.

If you're doing Java EE, then you'll probably have a web site, if so, you might want to use [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/), possibly in conjunction with [WindowLicker](http://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/)

If you have a database or jms broker, make sure each developer HAS THEIR OWN! This is very important - makes sure everybody has a copy that they can do what they like with, and obviously the continuous integration (CI) environment must have its own copy too!

The pay back for such an environment can be huge.  On my current project, we have a two-click-to-production automation coming straight out of TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below set:

Spring Tool Suite [www.springsource.org/‎](http://www.springsource.org/%E2%80%8E) - IDE with maven plugin for development and Accurev plugin for repo management.

Accurev [www.accurev.com](http://www.accurev.com) - For source code repository/version management.

Maven [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org)- For build process.

Hudson [hudson-ci.org/‎](http://hudson-ci.org/) - to Automate build and integration.

JIRA [www.atlassian.com/JIRA‎](http://www.atlassian.com/JIRA%E2%80%8E)- For bug/issue tracking.

Rally [www.rallydev.com](http://www.rallydev.com) - For project management.